# run a prolog code with swipl in a command line

Tags: command-line, prolog, server, swi-prolog

I am searching for `swipl` the similar feature as `perl -e` 
In particular, I want to run prolog code in this fashion:

```
swipl --wanted-flag "fact(a). message:-writeln('hello')." -g "message" -t halt
```

This is possible to do with

```
 swipl -f file -g "message" -t halt
```

where the prolog clauses are written in `file`

I am running swipl on the server side that takes user input as prolog clauses, therefore writing a file on the server is not a good idea.

Comment: You can preprocess the input (easy to do with `read/1` etc. since a Prolog program has a natural representation as a sequence of Prolog terms) and assert clauses with `assertz/1`. In your example, the eventual invocation of SWI Prolog could be `swipl -g "assertz(fact(a)), assertz(message :- writeln('hello')), message" -t halt` after preprocessing.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is to use [`load_files/2` with the option `stream`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=load_files/2), and load from standard input, not from an argument (you can still pass the entry point as an argument, I guess):

Say in a file `fromstdin.pl` you have:

```
main :-
    load_files(stdin, [stream(user_input)]),
    current_prolog_flag(argv, [Goal|_]),
    call(Goal),
    halt.
main :- halt(1).
```

and with this you can do:

```
$ echo 'message :- format("hello~n").' | swipl -q -t main fromstdin.pl -- message
|: hello
```

The comments by @false to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561323/swi-prolog-remove-before-user-input-in-compiled-program/30570563#30570563) and the question will tell you what this `|:` is, if you are wondering, but if it annoys you, just do:

```
$ echo 'message :- format("hello~n").' \
    | swipl -q -t main fromstdin.pl -- message \
    | cat
hello
```

instead.

This will let you read any Prolog from standard input and call an arbitrary predicate from it. Whether this is a clever thing to do, I don't know. I would also not be surprised if there is a much easier way to achieve the same.

Comment: your code worked for me but it doesnt work when I modify it for my application. My prolog code contains also directives (e.g. `:- op(601, xfx, (/)). `).
It also employs compiled prolog code and I use the following command line command: `echo "bla bla..." | swipl -x binary -t main load_code.pl -- 'online_demo(1)'`, where `online_demo/1` is defined in `binary`.
The error is the following:
`ERROR: '<meta-call>'/1: Undefined procedure: main/1
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         main/0
`